# SharePoint 2010 designer workflow error

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I have a SP2010 designer workflow in SharePoint Online 2013.  It fails for 50% of the time. Says Failed on Start(retrying) with error log

> The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information

But once I terminate and re-run the workflow it runs fine. So doesn't look like data issue. How do I debug these errors?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, This error commonly results from one of two situations:

- One of the list fields was removed or changed, but the workflow was not updated to account for the change and is therefore trying to set a value for the old field. You should check all Update List Item actions in your workflow and make sure they are setting appropriate values for fields and that those fields exist on the list.
- There is a data type error wherein the workflow is trying to set a value in a field in the list item using the wrong data type. You should confirm that the Return Field As operation in their lookup is of the correct data type.